# Веб-приложение для вывода данных со стороннего API

Tags: javascript, api

Как делается веб-приложение, в котором по запросу, введенному в форме, с сервера приходят данные из json-файла и отображаются в виде таблицы? Может есть какие-то примеры по аналогии или похожие?

Comment: ну а с чём тут проблемы у вас? как вы и написали делаете запрос на сервер, получаете данные в зависиомсти от ввода и при получении json создаете таблицу например с количеством ячеёк равных например  длинне масива и в каждую заносите значение, потом отображаёте

Comment: Просто я впервые это делаю и как-то в растерянности, был бы пример какой-то.

Comment: я сейчас работаю над 1 проектом для себя, там использую сервер на node.js + mongodb, если интересно могу кратко объяснить показать что к чему

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо.

Comment: предлагаю продолжить обсуждение в чате : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63614/api